# Find and remove all records that have only numeric value in a character variable column in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame as below. c1,c2,c3 are there character columns

```
c1 c2 c3
A B C
D E F
2 M N
O P Q
6 T V
X Y Z
```

I need find and remove the records that only numeric values in column c1.

The resulting data frame should be like this:

```
c1 c2 c3
A B C
D E F
O P Q
X Y Z
```

How do i achieve this in R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this will do

```
df[!str_detect(df$c1,("([0-9])")),]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df <- data.frame(c1 = c("A", "D", "2", "0", "6", "X"),
                 c2 = c("B", "E", "M", "P", "T", "Y"),
                 c3 = c("C", "F", "N", "Q", "V", "Z"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df[!is.na(as.numeric(df$c1)),]
```